# Can not change display resolution on a Sony VGN-FZ21M

Tags: drivers, display, resolution

My Sony Notebook VGN-FZ21M does have a NVIDIA grafic card with a VESA G86 Board - e415h01. My Problem is, that i can not change the display resolution from 1024*768 (4:3) to 1980*1280.

I tried to in the system settings but there is no higher resolution shown. Also when i try to install a NVIDIA driver there is no difference.
Is it maybe possible to change resolution independently?

Answer (score 0):

you have Nvidia Settings Manager, maybe you should try with that

go to DASH HOME in the search type NVIDIA to find the NVIDIA X Server settings manager. 
Then open it and go to server settings.

In there you can tweak your settings

Answer (score 0):

Please run `lspci` and post the output in your question, so we can check for a form of hybrid graphics available on your laptop that may be the culprit in this case.